# Wrap Specific Pattern Of Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'd like to wrap specific text with `<i>` tag, tried few regex patterns and testing environments - without success.

Patterns:

- Number x Number x Number
- Number can be *int/float*, **x** can be *upper/lower* case.

Example: `"...6 text text text 60x60x2.0 text text text 2.5x20x20 ..."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?[xX]){2}\d+(\.\d+)?
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/eV3yM4/3)

The idea is:

- `\d+(\.\d+)?` - a number with optional floating part
- `[xX]` - a case insensitive x
- `(){2}` - repeated two times

Comment: It also matches single digit.

Comment: @noob, I didn't get the impression that this shouldn't be the case. It can be fixed by simply replacing `*` with `+`.

Comment: And now it also matches `2.5x20`. OP's specified the requirement as **only** three numbers.

Comment: Great, and when I want to wrap that string with <i>, as one group, Example: <i>60x60x2.0</i> --> what is the right way?

Comment: @Nate, use `str.replace(/(the_regex)/g, "<i>\1</i>")`. `\1` references the first group.

Comment: Tried it on the the real example, and doesn't seems to work for me. The string is:  " 6 Units of red pazel in the size of 1.2x60x60 with EVA technology. "

Comment: @Nate, try out `" 6 Units of red pazel in the size of 1.2x60x60 with EVA technology. ".replace(/((\d+(\.\d+)?[xX]){2}\d+(\.\d+)?)/, "<i>$1</i>")` in your browser console.

Comment: Thank You! That worked out. I have another string, which is in Hebrew - in that case it doesn't work. Hebrew string: "6 יחידות פאזל שחור במידות 60×60×1.2 ס"מ, עשוי EVA רך ומתאים לכלל פעילויות הכושר." --> Any suggestions?

Comment: It works for me after I copied the string and escaped the `"`, even though I might not be getting the same string that you are trying out. Check if the **x**-es and digits have the same character code as regular **x** and digits (it should work if they do). Experiment a little [here](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/js/regex#). If you still couldn't find a solution, post a new question as this is out of the scope of this one.

Answer (score 0):

As per the requirement following is my solution.

**Regex:** `\d+(\.\d)?[xX]\d+(\.\d)?[xX]\d+(\.\d)?`

**Explanation:** I guess it's pretty straight forward.

`\d+(\.\d)?` looks for *int* or *float* followed by **x** or **X**. This is done again and finally no **x** or **X**.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV3yM4/4)